# ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range when plotting scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, valueerror

I am attempting to generate a scatter plot to show data before and after the PCA transform, similar to this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-clearly-explained-how-when-why-to-use-it-and-feature-importance-a-guide-in-python-7c274582c37e).

To do this, I am running the following code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
axes[0].scatter(X.iloc[:,0], X.iloc[:,1], c=y)
axes[0].set_xlabel('x1')
axes[0].set_ylabel('x2')
axes[0].set_title('Before PCA')
axes[1].scatter(X_new[:,0], X_new[:,1], c=y)
axes[1].set_xlabel('PC1')
axes[1].set_ylabel('PC2')
axes[1].set_title('After PCA')
plt.show()
```

Which is causing this error to appear:

```
ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range
```

X is the preprocessed matrix of features, which contains 196 samples and 59 features. Whereas y is the dependent variable and contains two classes [0, 1].

Here is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-2c4f74ddce3f> in <module>
      1 fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
----> 2 axes[0].scatter(X.iloc[:,0], X.iloc[:,1], c=y)
      3 axes[0].set_xlabel('x1')
      4 axes[0].set_ylabel('x2')
      5 axes[0].set_title('Before PCA')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1597     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1598         if data is None:
-> 1599             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1600 
   1601         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4495                 offsets=offsets,
   4496                 transOffset=kwargs.pop('transform', self.transData),
-> 4497                 alpha=alpha
   4498                 )
   4499         collection.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in __init__(self, paths, sizes, **kwargs)
    881         """
    882 
--> 883         Collection.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    884         self.set_paths(paths)
    885         self.set_sizes(sizes)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in __init__(self, edgecolors, facecolors, linewidths, linestyles, capstyle, joinstyle, antialiaseds, offsets, transOffset, norm, cmap, pickradius, hatch, urls, offset_position, zorder, **kwargs)
    125 
    126         self._hatch_color = mcolors.to_rgba(mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'])
--> 127         self.set_facecolor(facecolors)
    128         self.set_edgecolor(edgecolors)
    129         self.set_linewidth(linewidths)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in set_facecolor(self, c)
    676         """
    677         self._original_facecolor = c
--> 678         self._set_facecolor(c)
    679 
    680     def get_facecolor(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in _set_facecolor(self, c)
    659         except AttributeError:
    660             pass
--> 661         self._facecolors = mcolors.to_rgba_array(c, self._alpha)
    662         self.stale = True
    663 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in to_rgba_array(c, alpha)
    277             result[mask] = 0
    278         if np.any((result < 0) | (result > 1)):
--> 279             raise ValueError("RGBA values should be within 0-1 range")
    280         return result
    281     # Handle single values.

ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range
```

I am unsure what is causing this error and would appreciate help in figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: What is y.shape?

Comment: @JohanC y.shape is (196, 1)

Comment: So, try `c=y.squeeze()`

Comment: What's the range values of X and y? Are they floats between 0 and 1?

Comment: @JohanC y.squeeze() seems to work! Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: @Phoenix this is a binary classification problem, so y values are either 0 or 1.

Comment: Weird , it works with after squeezing the array because the error message is talking about ValueError which means there is something wrong with the value of y not the size.

Comment: I think the values of y before squeezing like that:[ [0] [1] [0] [1]], right?

Comment: A shape of ` (196, 1) ` is 2D (`196x1`). You need a 1D array for the `c=` parameter.

Comment: I spent long time to debug from the source code of Matplotlib in GitHub , I am 100% your y shape is (1,196) not (196,1). If so, I have a clear explanation for why you had this error. Could you please make sure from the shape of y?

Comment: Because if you look to the end of error message triggered inside a function called to_rgba_array(c,alpha). If you open this function from the source code, you find inside this function that it starts with this if statement:   if (isinstance(c, np.ndarray) and c.dtype.kind in "if" and c.ndim == 2 and `c.shape[1] in [3, 4]`): Your y array satisifies all conditions except the last one which is `c.shap[1] in [3,4]`. If y's shape is really (196,1) should not access to this if-statement where the error should reside.

Comment: @Phoenix My y shape is (196, 1) and my X shape is (196, 59)

Comment: But because your y's shape satisfied this if condition, it goes into the body if statement and caused the error.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html#to_rgba_array

Comment: @JohanC if you write your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it as it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `c=` parameter of [`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) can be given in several ways:

- A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm. So a single number, or a list-like 1D sequence of numbers.
- A 2D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA. E.g. something like `[[1,0,0], [0,0,1]]`.  All these values need to be between 0 and 1. Moreover, there should be either 3 (for RGB) or 4 (for RGBA) values per entry.
- A sequence of colors of length n. E.g. `["red", "#B789C0", "turquoise"]`
- A single color format string. E.g. `"cornflowerblue"`.

Now, when an array of numbers is given, to be able to distinguish between the first and the second case, matplotlib just looks at the array dimension. If it is 1D, matplotlib assumes the first case. For 2D, it assumes the second case.  Note that also an `Nx1` or an `1xN` array is considered 2D.  You can use `np.squeeze()` to "squeeze out" the dummy second dimension.